# Concatenation of Static Text with DataBinding Value

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, concatenation, string-concatenation

Anyone can help me with how to concatenate static text with databinding value like for example:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSurveyUrl" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SurveyID")%>'></asp:Label>
```

now the text of this label becomes 1,2 or 3 (whatever SurveyID we're getting from table) but I would like it to become.

somepage.aspx?id=1

where "somepage.aspx?id=" is the fixed text and 1 is value that we got from expression. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving the static text in a format string:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSurveyUrl" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SurveyID", "somepage.aspx?id={0}")%>'></asp:Label>
```